# Obtain JSON request in Bokeh server application

Tags: python, bokeh

I would like to direct a user to a page hosted by the Bokeh server along with a bit of metadata.  For example I might want to direct a user to

```
http://my-server/my-page?var=value
```

I would then like to get the `{'var': 'value'}` request in my Bokeh server application code on the Python side so that I can respond accordingly.

Is this possible?  If so, how?

Comment: Yes, you can, just add header:` 'Content-Type: application/json'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Bokeh core dev pointed me to this documentation page:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#accessing-the-http-request

In particular, this is available on the document object:

```
# request.arguments is a dict that maps argument names to lists of strings,
# e.g, the query string ?N=10 will result in {'N': [b'10']}

args = curdoc().session_context.request.arguments

try:
  N = int(args.get('N')[0])
except:
  N = 200
```